# Capture mouse cursor in screenshot

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing Mac desktop application, where I am capturing the screen using

```
CGImageRef screenShot = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectInfinite, kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowImageDefault);
```

The problem is, I am expecting it should show the mouse cursor too, but it's not showing.

Do I need to enable any settings for that?

I tried the following before calling this function:

```
CGDisplayShowCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
    
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);
```

, but it didn't work.

When I checked using following

```
bool bCursor = CGCursorIsDrawnInFramebuffer(); /* This returns false */

bCursor = CGCursorIsVisible();  /* This returns true */
```

, te value says the cursor was not drawn in the frame buffer, however the cursor is visible.

I suppose I only need to do is to draw the cursor in the frame buffer, how do I do this?.

Comment: As on 2016, Now i am not using CG framework to capture the stream of desktop images, now i moved on AVFoundation framework, which works very smoothly and have added mouse cursor inbuilt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems, framebuffer doesn't give me the mouse cursor, so i am drawing my own, this is the code snippet , might be help full to you guys,

```
-(CGImageRef)appendMouseCursor:(CGImageRef)pSourceImage{
    // get the cursor image 
    NSPoint mouseLoc; 
    mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation]; //get cur

    NSLog(@"Mouse location is x=%d,y=%d",(int)mouseLoc.x,(int)mouseLoc.y);

    // get the mouse image 
    NSImage *overlay    =   [[[NSCursor arrowCursor] image] copy];

    NSLog(@"Mouse location is x=%d,y=%d cursor width = %d, cursor height = %d",(int)mouseLoc.x,(int)mouseLoc.y,(int)[overlay size].width,(int)[overlay size].height);

    int x = (int)mouseLoc.x;
    int y = (int)mouseLoc.y;
    int w = (int)[overlay size].width;
    int h = (int)[overlay size].height;
    int org_x = x;
    int org_y = y;

    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(pSourceImage);
    size_t width =  CGImageGetWidth(pSourceImage);
    int bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(pSourceImage);

    unsigned int * imgData = (unsigned int*)malloc(height*bytesPerRow);

    // have the graphics context now, 
    CGRect bgBoundingBox = CGRectMake (0, 0, width,height);

    CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(imgData, width, 
                                                  height, 
                                                  8, // 8 bits per component 
                                                  bytesPerRow, 
                                                  CGImageGetColorSpace(pSourceImage), 
                                                  CGImageGetBitmapInfo(pSourceImage));

    // first draw the image 
    CGContextDrawImage(context,bgBoundingBox,pSourceImage);

    // then mouse cursor 
    CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(0, 0, width,height),pSourceImage);

    // then mouse cursor 
    CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(org_x, org_y, w,h),[overlay CGImageForProposedRect: NULL context: NULL hints: NULL] );


    // assuming both the image has been drawn then create an Image Ref for that 

    CGImageRef pFinalImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return pFinalImage; /* to be released by the caller */
}
```