# Is there a way to get the mouse cursor icon in a C/C++ application on Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, cursor, icons, mouse

Let me detail what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a C/C++ (no Objective-C) application that captures the screen (using methods from Quartz Display Services such as CGImageRef and CGWindowListCreateImage).

However, these methods do not also capture the mouse cursor icon, so could you please let me know if there is any way of capturing this using only C/C++ (and no Objective-C or Cocoa)?

Thank you,

Mihnea

P.S. I know that there is a similar post ( [Not displaying Mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008630/not-displaying-mouse-cursor) ), but the only valid answer on that thread uses Objective-C code, and I cannot use that in my application.

Comment: Please detail why you can't use Objective-C.

Comment: ... I had a hunch that I should include this explanation :)... my application is a cross-platform screen-sharing browser plugin, that relies on Firebreath. I'm trying to write a single codebase in C++ (the plugin is already working on Windows), and would prefer to use only C++, to make packaging, maintenance and distribution easier

Comment: Besides this, I'm having problems including multiple projects in the same Firebreath solution (haven't found any useful HelloWorld-like samples that show how to include multiple projects/libraries in the same Firebreath solution), so building a separate .so just for the purpose of the mouse icon is a nuisance.

Comment: anything you can do an Objective C, can be done in C, just with a lot more lines of code

Comment: @GradyPlayer That's like saying "Everything that can be done in any high level language can be done in machine code".

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe no it isn't... it is saying if you have an easy way to do it in Objective-C... then you can write equivalent C code with little trouble, Objective-C used to just be a C pre-processor... Every method is a function that accepts a pointer to self, the selector and the arguments... oh and the difference with your analogy aside from the hyperbole is that this solution would be portable